# Magento 2.3-2.4.4 : syntax error, unexpected ''username'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']' magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php(171)

Tags: magento, magento2.4.4

While running any magento command :
syntax error, unexpected ''username'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']'#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php(171)

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUKLH.png)

I am trying this command

rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*

rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*

chmod 777 -R pub/static/frontend/

rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*

rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*

rm -rf generated/*